# Publish mqtt message to topic from aws lambda using aws iot

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, mqtt, aws-lambda, aws-iot

I need to publish data from aws lambda through mqtt protocol using aws iot. i have created a lambda function with node.js code. like this

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    var awsIot = require('aws-iot-device-sdk');

    var device = awsIot.device({
        keyPath: 'samplepath/test.pem.key',
        certPath: 'samplepath/test.crt',
        caPath: 'samplepath',
        clientId: 'sampleId',
        region: 'us-east-1'
    });

    device
        .on('connect', function () {
            console.log('connected');
            device.publish('test_topic', JSON.stringify({ "test_name": "hello", "test_value": 1001 }));
            console.log('published successfully');
            callback(null, 'item added');
        });
}
```

I got mqtt message on subscriber. but lambda produce error message like this

```
Task timed out after 10.00 seconds
```

I have used context.succeed() instead of callback, lambda is exited properly. i cant get any messages on subscriber.

In both cases console prints *published successfully* message properly.

What is the issue related with my publishing code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I understand my lambda function is timing out when connecting to AWS
>   IoT. About the sdk we are using, the aws-iot-device-sdk is designed to
>   use inside of an embedded device. When we are using a Lambda function
>   or trying to publish in a computer, the best practice is use the
>   aws-sdk. Using the aws-sdk we don't need to use the certificates to
>   publish in the AWS IoT, we just use the AWS credentials to do this.
>   Also, with aws-sdk we can do administrative tasks in the IoT, we can
>   create a thing, create a certificate, etc.
>
> Coming to my code, the reason the function does not end and times out
>   is because the callback must be waiting for an asynchronous call to
>   finish execution, which I assume is being help up by the connection
>   being maintained from the function to IoT. The reason
>   context.succeed() exited properly but we did not get any messages must
>   be because context.succeed does not wait for our async calls to finish
>   execution.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you disconnect from the device after you published the message, otherwise Lambda will wait while the connection stays alive (see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-context.html, look for `callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop`).

To disconnect when done, simply change `callback(null, 'item added');` to

`device.end((err) => {
    callback(err, "item added");
});`